# Login form php without database - reloading

Tags: php, forms, authentication, reload

Is there any solution like `unset $msg` or something, that, when I reload the page,  the $msg stops?

here is my code:

index.php:

```
<form class="ligar" action="log.php" method="post">
        <p class="lig"><input name="username" type="text"      placeholder="Username"></p>
        <p class="lig"><input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
        <p class="lig"><input name="Entrar" type="submit" value="log"></p>
        <p class="error"><?php if(isset($_GET['msg']))
                         echo $_GET['msg'];
                        ?>
        </p>
</form>
```

log.php:

```
<?php 
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username =='john' AND $password=='abc') {
    header("Location:/detalhes.php");
} elseif ($username!='john' OR $password!='abc'){
    $msg = "Wrong, try again."; 
    header("Location:http://localhost/index.php?msg=$msg");
}
?>
```

Comment: Your `index.html` contains PHP, so that won't work unless you instructed Apache to treat `.html` as PHP. If not, then rename it to `index.php`

Comment: yea i know, that's not the problem. That was a mistake by me when writing the code for you guys.

Comment: Ok. Now, I don't quite understand what you mean by *"when i reload the page, the $msg stops"*, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: You need to remove it from the URL by redirecting it without `msg=$msg`

Comment: no, he wants to unload the value stored in the GET parameter

Comment: Well, "the function" doesn't stop when i reload the page, ikr, im contradicting myself on that since i assign a specific link,but i can't find a way. I want to refresh a page after the msg shows and the $msg disappears..

Comment: do not pass the parameter as GET, set the error message to a session object and then redirect without the get parameter. after processing the Error message, unset the session.

Comment: @StefanoL can you specify the code? I was into that first, the GET was the only way i could get through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the job: (untested)

```
<?php 
session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username =='john' AND $password=='abc') {
    header("Location:/detalhes.php");
} elseif ($username!='john' OR $password!='abc'){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Wrong, try again.";     
    header("Location:http://localhost/index.php");
}
?>
```

log.php

```
<?
session_start();
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['msg']))
    echo $_SESSION['msg'];
    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, if first time you enter the wrong credentials, the `log.php` code redirects the page to

```
http://localhost/index.php?msg=Wrong,%20try%20again.
```

So if you reload the page via browser, obviosly the uri remains the same, so you still get the error message in the `$_GET['msg']` variable.

**EDIT** <strike>I don't think there's a solution to that using only HTML+PHP.</strike>

You can convert the form post to an AJAX request and show/hide the error code via javascript, so you don'
t need to change the uri.

The web is full of easy examples on how to implement an AJAX login form.

**EDIT** Well, as @Stefano L said, you can use session cookies so you don't need to use any javascript at all.

Comment: i really want to use only html and php. I'm accepting other ways to do it anyway.